# Why are the electrodes in thermodynamic equilibrium for a working solar cell?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, equilibrium, non-equilibrium, solar-cells

I was reading a paper that performed simulation of a solar cell under illuminated conditions. Obviously, in these conditions, the device is out of thermodynamic equilibrium. For example the distribution of charges can clearly not be computed by a Boltzmann distribution.

However, as one of their boundary conditions, they use the hypothesis that the electrodes *are indeed in equilibrium* (unlike the rest of the device). Using notions of schottky contact, and equilibrium distribution laws, this allows them to derive a boundary condition for the charge concentration at the electrodes.

However, I don't understand the physical meaning of this. what is the physical motivation fot the assumption that the electrodes of a working device are in equilibrium ?

Here is a link to the paper (I think it is in public access). You can find mention of this assumption on page 3/9, end of the first column:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313875095_Improving_Perovskite_Solar_Cells_Insights_From_a_Validated_Device_Model

N.B: it does not seem to be a common assumption. Other authors might choose other variants for boundary conditions

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: I included a link in the body of the question. Thanks for the suggestion !